# domain with only one or two characters

Tags: domains

I came across some sites that have only 2 or even 1 charachter for the domain name like hp.com, u.bb and 9.bb

How come? as we know that when registering a domain name we must provide at least 3 characters.

Comment: Depends on registrar. The "owners" of the TLD have flexibility in their rules. (And in [almost] all TLDs all the two letter combinations and perhaps three are ... gone.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what the tld requires. For example, even though for `.me` domains you need 3 letters, many companies [are granted an exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.me) for example `fb.me`, `wp.me`. They are probably paying for this privilege :-)

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has an [article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain).

Answer (score 3):

**Single-letter second-level domains** are domain names in which the second-level domain consists of only one letter, **such as x.com**. In 1993, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (**IANA**) **explicitly reserved** all single-letter and single-digit second-level domain names in the top-level domains **com, net, and org**, and grandfathered those that had already been assigned. In December 2005, ICANN considered auctioning these domains.

Emphasis/Mine

Two letter domains where reserved to prevent confusion with two letter country code TLDs.

[Source/Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain)

Answer (score -1):

It is theoretically possible but usually all that domains are taken. Special resellers like 1-single-letter-domains.com offer such domains to buy, but the prices are much higher than usual domains. But if you want only a 2-letter domain you can get it much cheaper than 1-letter. 1=$$$$ price, 2=60+ USD. You need to order a search for it